# How to use IPCapture Library for mjpeg streaming

Tags: java, android, mjpeg

I found this library named IPCapture which I could use for mjpeg streaming over IP Cameras. How can I integrate this seperate class to my existing code.?

Answer (score 0):

Found a jar file of it and managed to use it. pretty stupid question to be honest :D